# Bounded solutions of a linear non-autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So consider the following linear non-autonomous ODE:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{x}_1  \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  t^2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1  \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}  \; \; \; \;(1)
\end{equation}
where for convenience we have denoted $x_1$ for $x_1(t)$ and $x_2$ for $x_2(t)$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am curious if there exists initial conditions (apart from the trivial one) such that the solution remains bounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$. This seems like a pretty standard problem, does anybody have an idea how to go about with this?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1\\\dot{x}_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}t^2&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{cases}\dot{x}_1=t^2x_1+x_2\\\dot{x}_2=x_1\end{cases}$

$\therefore\ddot{x}_1=t^2\dot{x}_1+2tx_1+\dot{x}_2=t^2\dot{x}_1+2tx_1+x_1$

$\ddot{x}_1-t^2\dot{x}_1-(2t+1)x_1=0$

But since this ODE unfortunately relates to Triconfluent Heun equation (http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E4 and http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunT), it is very difficult to analyse further.